# Initialize all the elements of an array to the same number

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

Some time ago my old teacher posted this code saying that it is another way to initialize an array to the same number (other than zero of course).

Three in this case.

He said that this way is slightly better than the `for` loop. Why do I need the left shift operator? Why do I need another array of long?
I don't understand anything what's happening here.

```
int main() {

    short int A[100];

    long int v = 3;
    v = (v << 16) + 3;
    v = (v << 16) + 3;
    v = (v << 16) + 3;
    long *B = (long*)A;

    for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
        B[i] = v;

    cout << endl;
    print(A,100);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it's supposed to be slightly better as it appears to have _undefined behaviour_. Is this supposed to be a performance enhancement?

Comment: Your teacher seems to assume that `long` is 4 times the size of `short int` - which is in no way guaranteed by the standard (and therefore wrong on some compilers, e.g.: MSVC)

Comment: Note that v ends up as `0x3000000300000030000003L`, assuming it doesn't overflow first. And that overflow is just the first problem with this code - this teacher should **not** be teaching C++.

Comment: Don't worry, your compiler doesn't understand it either. If that code works on a particular machine with a particular compiler, it's only by accident.

Comment: This is still using a for loop, it's just using a smaller loop with 25 iterations instead of 100 iterations. It would probably work if `sizeof(long)` is 8. But it won't be faster than standard methods.

Comment: it may not work at all due to misalignment between short and long

Comment: @MSalters if long is 64 and short is 16 bits as assumed by theacher. There is no overflow as far as i can see. And the value turns out to be 0x0003000300030003 (shifting 16 bits means shifting 4 characters in hex notation)

Comment: @MSalters actually 0x0003000300030003.

Comment: Your professor is working from an incorrect mental model that `A` and `B` are pointing to an array of 200 memory locations, and that `B[i]=v` is an instruction to set 8 of those memory locations to the 8 bytes comprising the value of v.

Comment: "GIve arguments to support the following conjectures: • if n>=10, the time required to initialize a matrix is not very important • if n<10, the time required to initialize a matrix is not very important" -- points to ponder 1.1, chapter 1, re rule 1, "Write clearly--don't be too clever", the classic, The Elements of Programming Style

Comment: Please re-tag. It is purely [C] question, not [C++]. The only plusplus-ish part is the `cout << endl` instruction, which has literary _nothing_ to do with the problem presented. Anyway it still **does use** the `for` loop!

Comment: @CiaPan Just because a C++ snippet is also a valid C snippet, that doesn't automatically make it C instead of C++; there are cases where code is valid in both languages, but has different results in each (e.g., `sizeof('a')` is `sizeof(int)` in C, but `sizeof(char)` in C++).

Comment: @JustinTime As far as I can see OP doesn't use `sizeof` in the presented code, so your reasoning is quite off-topic. He does, however, use `printf()` which belongs to standard C library, and a C-style `main()` declaration. Anyway the main issue here is superipmosing another type on the data by casting pointers, which is UB both in C and in C++.

Comment: @CiaPan Where do you see printf()?It's just a print function wrote by me,that I forgot to delete.

Comment: @Cimmerian_Perspective You're right, I must have misread the last line. Anyway, the code is purely C (except the single newline output), and that's the main part of what I said.

Comment: @CiaPan I've always declared the main in that way,I didn't know was a C thing

Comment: One old coder would like to say something in defence of another: When I learned C a program was expected to run in one environment forever. Compilers changed seldom, languages "never", C was "mature", C++ a rumour, code portability a myth. [] and * were synonymous. We knew our platform and types. We routinely cast pointers & hard-calculated offsets. _Optimisations like this were meaningful._ (It is "SO sad" that @MSalters can earn points for "ignorance and disrespect".) **Since "my old C(++) landscape" no longer exists & such techniques outdated, please do understand it but then unlearn it**

Comment: @AlanK: I've worked with *the* old K&R compiler. Not *a* K&R compiler, but the original C compiler by the original authors. You are mixing up a few time periods there. C was stable perhaps between C90 and C99, but at that time `[]` and `*` were no longer synonymous (that really was a B thing, not C). I understand the comment about portability - C wasn't the first ISO-standardized language, e.g. Algol preceded it, but C was the first language to be both standardized and useful. Not everyone realized it and wrote portable code, but there is a long history of writing bad code.

Comment: @MSalters: Timeline points taken, but you missed mine which were
(1) "Code quality is subjective, depends on era, environment etc". There was a time when the optimisation in question had value. My 1st 10 yrs in C was on a port of MS C to BTOS (long dead) "90% K&R + 25% MS improvement;-)". Hardware proprietary. I wrote "bad code" then that I wouldn't teach today. It served its purpose and still runs in a few places in Namibia (targeted for switch-off since 1998;-). That's IT for you and the reason for our differing perspective on this question. (2) Arithmetically (3 << 16) + 3 == 0x30003.

Comment: That was an example of code that is valid as both C and C++, @CiaPan, but has different results in C than in C++.  The intent was to say, "If the provided code can plausibly be valid for multiple languages, then please treat it as the language the asker says it is.  Please don't tell them they're wrong about which language they're using."

Comment: @Cimmerian_Perspective My apologies for the delayed reply, but your code is entirely valid C++.  `int main() { /* ... */ }` is defined in the C++ standard (specifically, `[basic.start.main/2]`) as one of the two definitions of `main()` that all compliant compilers are required to support, and `printf()` is a member of the C++ standard library, supplied in the header `<cstdio>` (I'm aware you didn't use it).  That it is _also_ valid C is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

He assumes that `long` is four times longer than `short` (that is not guaranteed; he should use int16_t and int64_t).

He takes that longer memory space (64 bits) and fills it with four short (16 bits) values. He is setting up the values by shifting bits by 16 spaces.

Then he wants to treat an array of shorts as an array of longs, so he can set up 100 16-bit values by doing only 25 loop iteration instead of 100.

That's the way your teacher thinks, but as others said this cast is undefined behavior.

Comment: Technically speaking, the cast itself is just fine. It is the access through the pointer of wrong type that has UB.

Comment: Though technically this is UB, any compiler that uses 16-bit shorts and 64-bit longs for which this didn't work exactly as expected I would consider broken.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker You can consider whatever you want, of course. But the spec is the spec, and compilers frequently do things that you might consider surprising or broken when undefined behavior is about.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I am pretty sure that GCC will make assumptions based on strict aliasing rules that will break in the presence of this code. In fact, almost any compiler that has any pretensions to optimization will.

Comment: Yes, GCC will properly warn you that this code violates aliasing rules...and will produce working code anyway. I have no argument that this code is against the rules, only that a compiler should do it anyway.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Your use of "should" is simply wrong. (You might try to articulate your assumptions/theory re what a complier "should" do & then try to find some justification for it. As opposed to what the language & gcc specifications say. Or articulate what you otherwise mean by "a compiler should do"--maybe what some hypothetical model of compilation illustrating principles of compilation that you have in mind would do regardless of what a compiler acutally should do and despite the principle of compilation that an implementation does what its specification & implementers guarantee.)

Comment: I'm using "should" here to mean "what I think is right", nothing more, nothing less. As I've said again and again, I understand the spec says the behavior is undefined. That means it can do anything. What I'd personally prefer it to do is this--that's my opinion, nothing more. I do not apologize for my opinions.

Answer (score 76):

There are many ways to fill an array with the same value, and if you are concerned about performance then you need to measure.

C++ has a dedicated function for filling an array with a value, and I would use this (after `#include <algorithm>` and `#include <iterator>`):

```
std::fill(std::begin(A), std::end(A), 3);
```

You shouldn't underestimate what optimizing compilers can do with something like this.

If you are interested in seeing what the compiler does, then Matt Godbolt's [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org) is a very good tool if you're prepared to learn a little bit of assembler. As you can see from [here](https://godbolt.org/g/Dvg9Rh), compilers can optimize the `fill` call to twelve (and a bit) 128-bit stores with any loops unrolled. Because compilers have knowledge of the target environment they can do this without encoding any target-specific assumptions in the source code.

Comment: Why did you make the array `extern` in your example at Godbolt's? This results in GCC doing lots of irrelevant stuff for the case when `A` is not properly aligned, making your point not really obvious. Why not simply remove the `extern` keyword?

Answer (score 44):

What an absolute load of hogwash.

1. For starters, `v` will be computed at *compile time*.
2. The behaviour of dereferencing `B` following `long *B = (long*)A;` is undefined as the types are not related. `B[i]` is a dereference of `B`.
3. There's no justification whatsoever for the assumption that a `long` is four times larger than a `short`.

Use a `for` loop in the simple way and trust the compiler to optimise. Pretty please, with sugar on top.

Comment: Technically, it's not the cast creating B which is undefined behaviour, it is the access through it.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Correct (as always ;-)), These things are important. I've amended.

Answer (score 21):

The question has the C++ tag (no C tag), so this should be done in C++ style:

```
// C++ 03
std::vector<int> tab(100, 3);

// C++ 11
auto tab = std::vector<int>(100, 3);
auto tab2 = std::array<int, 100>{};
tab2.fill(3);
```

Also the teacher is trying outsmart the compiler which can do mind-blowing things. There is no point to do such tricks since the compiler can do it for you if configured properly:

- [Your code assemblies](https://godbolt.org/g/AakLHz)
- [Your code assemblies with tick removed](https://godbolt.org/g/aMKhT6)
- [Array approach](https://godbolt.org/g/qCw48F)
- [Vector approach](https://godbolt.org/g/UswxVu)

As you can see, the `-O2` result code is (almost) the same for each version. In case of `-O1`, tricks give some improvement.

So the bottom line, you have to make a choice:

- Write hard-to-read code and do not use compiler optimizations
- Write readable code and use `-O2`

Use the Godbolt site to experiment with other compilers and configurations.
See also [the latest cppCon talk](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4).

Comment: +1 for *So the bottom line [...]*. As someone not beginner, not pro, OP's code is very difficult to understand. It may work as a fun fact (if it actually does, seeing the other answers), but the message is obscure, and it shouldn't be promoted as "another method", but as a "fun fact", explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

As explained by other answers, the code violates type aliasing rules and makes assumptions that are not guaranteed by the standard.

If you really wanted to do this optimization by hand, this would be a correct way that has well-defined behaviour:

```
long v;
for(int i=0; i < sizeof v / sizeof *A; i++) {
    v = (v << sizeof *A * CHAR_BIT) + 3;
}

for(int i=0; i < sizeof A / sizeof v; i++) {
    std:memcpy(A + i * sizeof v, &v, sizeof v);
}
```

The unsafe assumptions about the sizes of the objects were fixed by the use of `sizeof`, and the aliasing violation was fixed by using `std::memcpy`, which has well-defined behaviour regardless of the underlying type.

That said, it's probably best to keep your code simple and let the compiler do its magic instead.

---

> Why I need the left shift operator?

The point is to fill a bigger integer with multiple copies of the smaller integer. If you write a two-byte value `s` to a big integer `l`, then **shift** the bits left for two bytes (my fixed version should be clearer about where those magic numbers came from) then you'll have an integer with two copies of the bytes that constitute the value `s`. This is repeated until all pairs of bytes in `l` are set to those same values. To do the shift, you need the shift operator.

When those values are copied over an array that contains an array of the two-byte integers, a single copy will set the value of multiple objects to the value of the bytes of the larger object. Since each pair of bytes has the same value, so will the smaller integers of the array.

> Why I need another array of `long`?

There are no arrays of `long`. Only an array of `short`.

Comment: Is this really the case? Strictly speaking, I think there is no guarantee that the size of long is a multiple of the size of short. Also, longs might be stored as little endian, while longs are long endian (it's crazy, but...). Copying the underlying bits like this might end up in a trap representation for the short values. So, I think this approach is still UB. Maybe the safe way would be to use `short int a[4]` instead of `long`?

Comment: @chi good point. One could use the fixed size integers which would safely fail to compile when they aren't available. Your suggestion would also be safe and work on all esoteric systems as well. The arrays probably should be augmented with `alignas`. Your suggestion gives me a (probably silly) idea: Write two values to the output array, then copy those two, then copy four ... which would give fairly few calls to `memcpy` (log N) while avoiding setting up a large "source" array. This loop would have to be expanded compile time though to have any hope of being efficient

Answer (score 6):

The code your teacher has shown you is an ill-formed program, no diagnostic required, because it violates a requirement that pointers actually point to the thing they claim to be pointed to (otherwise known as "strict aliasing").

As a concrete example, a compiler can analyze your program, notice that `A` was not directly written to and that no `short` was written to, and prove that `A` was never changed once created.

All of that messing around with `B` can be proven, under the C++ standard, as not being able to modify `A` in a well formed program.

A `for(;;)` loop or even a ranged-for is likely to be optimized down to static initialization of `A`.  Your teacher's code, under an optimizing compiler, will optimize to undefined behavior.

If you really need a way to create an array initialized with one value, you could use this:

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
auto index_over(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  return [](auto&&f)->decltype(auto) {
    return f( std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}... );
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto index_upto(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> ={})
{
  return index_over( std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
template<class T, std::size_t N, T value>
std::array<T, N> make_filled_array() {
  return index_upto<N>()( [](auto...Is)->std::array<T,N>{
    return {{ (void(Is),value)... }};
  });
}
```

and now:

```
int main() {

  auto A = make_filled_array<short, 100, 3>();

  std::cout << "\n";
  print(A.data(),100);
}
```

creates the filled array at compile time, no loops involved.

Using [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/LMuniG) you can see that the array's value was computed at compile time, and the value 3 was extracted when I access the 50th element.

This is, however, overkill (and [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)).

Answer (score 2):

I think he is trying to reduce the number of loop iterations by copying multiple array elements at the same time. As other users already mentioned here, this logic would lead to undefined behavior.

If it is all about reducing iterations then with loop-unrolling we can reduce the number of iterations. But it won't be significantly faster for such smaller arrays.

```
int main() {

    short int A[100];

    for(int i=0; i<100; i+=4)
    {
        A[i] = 3;
        A[i + 1] = 3;
        A[i + 2] = 3;
        A[i + 3] = 3;
    }
    print(A, 100);
}
```

Comment: The point of the optimization is not *just* loop unrolling. It also reduces the number of copies (writing a single 64 bit number is faster than writing 4 counts of 16 bit numbers), which your suggestion does not do. That said, your suggestion is at least not buggy like the one in the question.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion doesn't try to reduce number of copy operations.

Comment: @user2079303 "writing a single 64 bit number is faster than writing 4 counts of 16 bit numbers", that is also target dependant. On a 16 bit target you'll end up with 4 copy operations for one 64bit copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::array` instead of built in array along with a `make_array` function template that will return a `std::array` with all elements set to `3`(or other given number) as shown below.

```
template<std::size_t N> std::array<int, N> constexpr make_array(int val)
{
    std::array<int, N> tempArray{};
    for(int &elem:tempArray)
    {
        elem = val;
    }
    return tempArray;
}
int main()
{
    //-------------------------------V-------->number of elements  
    constexpr auto arr  = make_array<8>(5);
    //-------------------------------^---->value of element to be initialized with

    
    //lets confirm if all objects have the expected value 
    for(const auto &elem: arr)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl; //prints all 5 
    }
    
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3M78MaYEj)